# Convert image into black and white image without using Gray-scale of Device in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

We have to convert the image into black and white image after capturing from camera.

Please help for converting colored image into black and white image.

Thanks,
Rishu

Answer (score 1):

One easy way of doing it is to take the average of the RGB values and use that as the new RGB value. Let's say rgb=(45, 60, 20) would be rgb_gray=(41,41,41)

It is all described pretty well [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale)